# React rerender only one child

Tags: reactjs, rerender

in my form i have a few dropdown components. Whenever first dropdown option changes i want to update props for the second dropdown and rerender it. My code looks like this

```
handleProjectChange(option) {
    //this.setState({ selectedProject: option })
    this.refs.phase.props = option.phases;
    //this.refs.forceUpdate()
    this.refs.phase.render()
}

render() {
    var projectOptions = this.projectOptions
    var defaultProjectOption = this.state.selectedProject
    var phaseOptions = defaultProjectOption.phaseOptions
    var defaultPhaseOption = phaseOptions[0]
    var workTypeOptions = api.workTypes().map(x => { return  { value: x, label: x } })
    var defaultWorkTypeOption = workTypeOptions[0]
    return (
        <div>
            <Dropdown ref='project' options={projectOptions} value={defaultProjectOption} onChange={this.handleProjectChange.bind(this)} />
            <Dropdown ref='phase' options={phaseOptions} value={defaultPhaseOption} />
            <Dropdown options={workTypeOptions} value={defaultWorkTypeOption} />                
            <button className="btn btn-primary"  onClick={this.handleAddClick.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But props are not changed, so it rerenders the same options. At the moment im just rerendering entire form by setting new state on it. Is there any way to rerender only one child/Dropdown with new props?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to put the selected option in first dropdown `selectedProject` in state.

And inside your render function, fetch/ populate the options in the second dropdown, dependent on the selected project.

Flow will then be:

- User selects an option in the first dropdown.
- This triggers `handleProjectChange()`
- Inside `handleProjectChange()`, the newly selected option is put in state, by a `this.setState()` call
- Because state changed, react re-runs the entire `render()` function.
- Under the hood, react figures out that only the second dropdown has changed, so react will only re-render the second drop-down on your screen/ in the DOM.

Comment: Ah, now i just realized it will rerender only second dropdown. But logic before return is executed, it maybe be slow with huge dropdowns, i guess i should cache it. I cant upvote your answer due to 15 reputation points. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although React does have a reconciliation algorithm that dynamically checks whether each component should be rerenader or not in every rendering of its parent, it doesn't always work as we intended.

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

For this kind of issues, you have two options. You can use either React.pureComponent or React.useMemo().